# Passing values from one page to another

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am passing a parameter to my navigation URL,the passed parameter value has to be return this value  in another page.
I am having URL in abc solution default.aspx.cs and i want to navigate to xyz solutions sample.aspx

```
string InvestigationPageUrl = NavigationService.GetNavigationUrl(Investigation.Investigationpage, new DetailsParameters(CurrentParameters.ReceiptNumber));

Message_Panel.Summary = string.Format(Investigation.Investigation_message, InvestigationPageUrl);
```

1. passing without parameter I am able to navigate
2. passing with parameter I am getting error as

> could not establish a connection to one of the following addresses:
>   [10.31.80.146:9098, 10.31.80.146:9099]; make sure the
>   "remote-addresses" configuration element contains an address and port
>   of a running TcpAcceptor

BaseExceptionDetail:

> netcom.Online.estimate.Framework.Instrumentation.Exceptions.CoherenceCacheProviderException:
>   could not establish a connection to one of the following addresses:
>   [10.31.80.146:9098, 10.31.80.146:9099]; make sure the
>   "remote-addresses" configuration element contains an address and port
>   of a running TcpAcceptor --->
>   Tangosol.Net.Messaging.ConnectionException: could not establish a
>   connection to one of the following addresses: [10.31.80.146:9098,
>   10.31.80.146:9099]; make sure the "remote-addresses" configuration element contains an address and port of a running TcpAcceptor
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: Does something like NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/testing.xaml?id=4711", UriKind.Relative)) work ?

Comment: IT DOESN'T WORKED,STILL SAME ERROR.

Comment: What does you uri look like?